# How to see summary statistics for only few x variables

Tags: r

I have performed a fit for a linear model using lm in R, which has over 1000 dummy variables. After regression, I have gotten summary statistics in a variable called "fit". I am interested in extracting the coefficients and summary statistics of only a very limited set of 10 independent variables. How can I see summary statistics for only those variables? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you built a model named `mod`, you can extract fit information for a set of named variables from `summary(mod)$coefficients`:

```
data(iris)
mod = lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=iris)
summary(mod)$coefficients[c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"),]
#                Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
# Petal.Length  0.7091320 0.05671929 12.502483 7.656980e-25
# Petal.Width  -0.5564827 0.12754795 -4.362929 2.412876e-05
```